# Running ffmpeg via PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg

So the end goal is to have a php script that, given a list of images, will automatically create a slideshow video with transitions and text overlays and maybe an audio track as well.

I'm competent in coding PHP but not experienced in command line stuff.

We have a dedicated server and I got hosting company to install ffmpeg for me.

So I thought I'd start simple and slowly build up to ultimate goal. But I'm really struggling. I've spent a couple of days trying all sorts of things with very little success.

I found this post with some excellent examples https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg but I can't get any of them to work. Which makes me think that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

So this does work for me - I get a nice little 30 sec video slideshow of 6 images displaying for 5 secs each:

```
$ffmpeg="/usr/bin/ffmpeg";
exec($ffmpeg.' -f concat -safe 0 -i input.txt -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y out.mp4 2>&1', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

and this is input.txt

```
file /home/webvivre/public_html/videos/test/i1.jpg
duration 5
file /home/webvivre/public_html/videos/test/i2.jpg
duration 5
file /home/webvivre/public_html/videos/test/i3.jpg
duration 5
file /home/webvivre/public_html/videos/test/i4.jpg
duration 5
file /home/webvivre/public_html/videos/test/i5.jpg
duration 5
file /home/webvivre/public_html/videos/test/i6.jpg
duration 5
```

But this (basically taken from example in link above - have only changed image names and ffmpeg location) doesn't work for me:

```
$code="/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i i1.jpg -loop 1 -i i2.jpg -loop 1 -i i3.jpg -filter_complex \" [0:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,trim=duration=5,blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; [1:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,trim=duration=5,blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; [2:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125,trim=duration=5,blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; [v0][v1][v2] concat=n=3:v=1:a=0, format=yuv420p[v]\" -map '[v]' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -q:v 1 out.mp4 2>&1";
exec($code,$output);
var_dump($output);
```

This is the output:

```
array(25) { [0]=> string(67) "ffmpeg version 2.8.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers" [1]=> string(56) " built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)" [2]=> string(1147) " configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect" [3]=> string(40) " libavutil 54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100" [4]=> string(40) " libavcodec 56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100" [5]=> string(40) " libavformat 56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101" [6]=> string(40) " libavdevice 56. 4.100 / 56. 4.100" [7]=> string(40) " libavfilter 5. 40.101 / 5. 40.101" [8]=> string(40) " libavresample 2. 1. 0 / 2. 1. 0" [9]=> string(40) " libswscale 3. 1.101 / 3. 1.101" [10]=> string(40) " libswresample 1. 2.101 / 1. 2.101" [11]=> string(40) " libpostproc 53. 3.100 / 53. 3.100" [12]=> string(38) "[mjpeg @ 0x183c720] Changeing bps to 8" [13]=> string(32) "Input #0, image2, from 'i1.jpg':" [14]=> string(61) " Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 33777 kb/s" [15]=> string(128) " Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1000x750 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc" [16]=> string(38) "[mjpeg @ 0x18427c0] Changeing bps to 8" [17]=> string(32) "Input #1, image2, from 'i2.jpg':" [18]=> string(61) " Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 41896 kb/s" [19]=> string(132) " Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1000x750 [SAR 300:300 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc" [20]=> string(38) "[mjpeg @ 0x1849fa0] Changeing bps to 8" [21]=> string(32) "Input #2, image2, from 'i3.jpg':" [22]=> string(61) " Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 34776 kb/s" [23]=> string(132) " Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1000x750 [SAR 300:300 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc" [24]=> string(81) "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_blend_10" }
```

And for reference, this is info provided to me by hosting company after installing ffmpeg for me:

```
svr01~ # ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 2.8.15 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
```

If someone could just shove me in the right direction to get the above working I'd be very grateful. I just know it's going to end up being something really simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two major problems:

- Your `ffmpeg` version is very outdated.
- The blend filter requires 2 inputs, but you are only giving it 1.

## Update

Your `ffmpeg` is so old that you're missing thousands of updates and hundreds of bug fixes and features. So before you do anything else you should update otherwise you may waste your time fighting a bug that's already been fixed.

For your OS it's easy to download an already compiled version from [johnvansickle.com](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). See [FAQ](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/) for install instructions. Then use the proper path in your script to point to the new `ffmpeg`.

Alternatively, you can follow a step-by-step compile guide at [FFmpeg Wiki: RHEL / CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos). This assumes your host allows this and you have access to the required compiling dependencies.

## Blend filter

You're getting a fatal error in the stderr output from `ffmpeg`:

```
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_blend_10
```

It's cryptic, but it means that you're only giving each [blend filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend-1) one input, but the blend filter requires two inputs (the top and bottom layers).

But forget using blend to crossfade. That's a slow, complicated, and outdated method.

## xfade filter

Use the xfade filter instead:

- [xfade filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: xfade filter gallery](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade)

The xfade filter is newer than FFmpeg 4.2, so make sure to download a version of `ffmpeg` from the current git master branch.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! Hosting company have updated ffmpeg for me and I can now create a simple slideshow video using xfade

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about your hosting, but i think you have possibly two issues

- commend line error, your command not well formated or need some more attributes (please try to add  `-filter_complex 'overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10'` to your commend)
- your hosting has no ffmpeg ( but i can see that they have ) or a recent ffmpeg

i have never seen the error `Parsed_blend_10` for ffmpeg, when i google it , if fond only this post  and a git issus without answer.

what you can do :

is better if you have an SSH access to server and try to execute the commend directly , if your web hosting cant give you that, the only think you can do is try to change your commend .

but , i think even if you manage to do that, you will need your own server, cause ffmpeg will consume alot of memory in server side ,wish the hosting company can't let you use it freely ,so they will ask you for upgrade .

and please, considere to try in your own host ( localy before going to host )

Comment: ffmpeg is definitely installed and working as I'm able to create a basic slideshow video with no transitions. We do have dedicated server hosting and will only be doing small amounts of video creation so none of that is a problem. I want to build the code dynamically using PHP so don't want to use SSH. Your suggested edit - is that in place of or in addition to the existing -filter_complex? And shouldn't it be surrounded in double quotes?

Comment: read my comment again, when i asked about doing an ssh , is to make sure that your commend is working fine in the server, to not lose time with workaround with php and at the end you find the problem it was the ffmpeg itself. also , as i sayed in my comment, i can see the ffmpeg is installed, im talking about version to see if all parames are acceptable with the version.  the edit that i asked for is to be sure that  overlay is working .

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to execute the code via SSH. I have tried replacing the filter_complex part of the code with what you suggested, also removed -map '[v]' and it didn't work. The last part of the output now is "[error]: malloc of size 2705088 failed" [44]=> string(21) "Video encoding failed" [45]=> string(18) "Conversion failed!"

Comment: see with your hosting about the ssh , you need to check they giving a ssh access with your plan ( again , i recommend that you execute the commend in your terminal before the server ) ,  about the malloc error , you need to also check if fppmeg is 64 or 32. all of that just to be sure that your commend is working fine before put it into php